Variable Doubling in Lagrangian Mechanics
I have been looking into how we handle non-conservative forces in Lagrangian mechanics.  They don't form a potential $V$ quite as easily as conservative forces do.  I have read in several places that there are approaches that involve doubling the degrees of freedom in order to construct potentials, allowing non-conservative forces to appear in variational problems.  However, the references I find don't provide direction as to how this is done.
How can one construct the potentials needed to solve physics problems with variation when non-conservative forces are present?

This is e.g. explained in C.R. Galley, arXiv:1210.2745. For a (possible non-conservative) generalized force $Q_j(q,\dot{q},t)$, the potential is
$$ -Q_j(q_+,\dot{q}_+,t)q^j_-,$$
cf. eq. (10) in my Phys.SE answer here.

I’m not sure this is a good answer: it basically sends to another post where there is a detailed and very good answer.  If nothing more is needed here then is this question not a duplicate of the one you linked?  (No offense to the OP as I just discovered the link myself.)

Hi @ZeroTheHero. Noted. It is a judgement call. I didn't want to close OP's question as a duplicate nor copy-paste my answer.
